# Find the point that makes two triangle equal

Tags: triangles

Can anyone help me with this problem? I draw the graph according to the problem, but don't know how to solve the problem. Thanks.

> A triangle has vertices with coordinates A(0,15), B(0,0), and C(10,0). Find the coordinates of point D on AC so that the area of triangle ABD is equal to the area of triangle DBC.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $BX$ be perpendicular to $AC$, $ABD$ and $DBC$ have the same altitude and since $[ABD]=[DBC]$ we get $AD=DC$. Use mid-point formula.

Answer (score 0):

$(x,y )$ is a coordinat which divided triangle into two equal area. 
$$\Delta= \frac12\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 15 \\ 
0& 0 \\ 
 x& y\\
0 &15
\end{vmatrix}= \frac12\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 0 \\ 
10& 0 \\ 
 x& y\\
0 &0
\end{vmatrix}$$
$$ 15x= 3y =\text{Half of area of triangle } \Delta ABC$$

Answer (score 0):

When $BD$ is the median then the area of $\Delta ABD$ is equal to the area of $\Delta BDC$.
Therefore the coordinates of $D$ is $(5, 7.5)$.